# Flash app for iPad; need to add high-res icons, but how?

Tags: ios, ipad, flash, air

Am publishing an app for iPad with Flash cc, air 4.0.
Problem: I need to include 2 high-res icons, 76x76 and 152x152.
But, nowhere on the Flash publish settings (under the icons tab) do I see a way to add those files. Still, Apple is giving me hassle about them.

Does anyone know how to add those extra icons, what to name them, where to put them so that when they are bundled in the IPA, they are included?

Thanks!!

This is my descriptor file ("cannot be parsed" error): Maybe I'm putting the two new icons in the wrong place in my code?? This is the whole descriptor file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
    <id>com.theapptrain.tpvision</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
    <filename>Hospitality TV</filename>
    <description></description>
    <!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.
<description>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
</description>
-->
<name>Hospitality TV</name>
<!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.
<name>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
</name>
-->
<copyright></copyright>
<initialWindow>
    <content>TPVisionApp.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
</initialWindow>
<customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
<allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
<icon>
    <image29x29>icons/tpvision29x29.png</image29x29>
    <image57x57>icons/tpvision57x57.png</image57x57>
    <image114x114>icons/tpvision114x114.png</image114x114>
    <image512x512>icons/tpvision512x512.png</image512x512>
    <image48x48>icons/tpvision48x48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>icons/tpvision72x72.png</image72x72>
    <image76x76>icons/tpvision76x76.png</image76x76>
    <image50x50>icons/tpvision50x50.png</image50x50>
    <image58x58>icons/tpvision58x58.png</image58x58>
    <image100x100>icons/tpvision100x100.png</image100x100>
    <image144x144>icons/tpvision144x144.png</image144x144>
    <image152x152>icons/tpvision152x152.png</image152x152>
    <image1024x1024>icons/tpvision1024x1024.png</image1024x1024>
</icon>
<supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
<iPhone>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array><string>2</string></array>
]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
<version>1.0</version>
</application>
```

Comment: I think the iPad icon size are 72 and 114?

Comment: yes! but it seems there are NEW ones now... 76x76 and 152x152.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html
I used to build my apps via flash too and I always entered the icons in the application description file as described on the linked site.

Comment: great idea! Tried that. And then got this error at publish...   
"Usage error, incorrect arguments" 
Any ideas??

Comment: hi - yes, that's the whole thing. I am using flash cc, upgraded, and air 4.0. ox maverick.

Comment: when I used air and flash to create apps I had this same problem, I had to install java 32 bit to get it to export properly. it might fix your problem too.

Comment: hmm, how do I do that? And, does that fix the icon problem?

Comment: you can remove java 7 and reinstall java 6 to get 32 bit, and that worked for me a while back, I can't guarantee that it will work for you though.

Comment: what s a 64-bit machine by the way?

Comment: a computer using a 64 bit os, since you are on a mac running maverick you are definitely using a 64 bit computer